# Beamer theme: not expected behaviours using different PDF readers

Tags: beamer, pdf, viewers, themes

I wish to use hsrmbeamertheme in my dissertation.
You can find and download it here: https://github.com/benjamin-weiss/hsrmbeamertheme .

Unfortunately, I have found a lot of not expected behaviours using different PDF readers (also running different PCs).
Please refer to the attached files.
The first pic is the correct layout (which is ok using Foxit Reader). The second and the third pics are screenshot of the compiled pdf opened with Adobe Reader XI.
Did you know how can I fix these problems?
Thank you so much in advance!

The code is on github: https://github.com/benjamin-weiss/hsrmbeamertheme/archive/master.zip

mwe.tex:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{sthlm}

\usepackage{
booktabs,
datetime,
dtklogos,
graphicx,
multicol,
pgfplots,
ragged2e,
tabularx,
tikz,
wasysym
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ %
language=[LaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
stepnumber=1,
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
breaklines=true,
frame=tb,
framerule=0.5pt,
tabsize=4,
framexleftmargin=0.5em,
framexrightmargin=0.5em,
xleftmargin=0.5em,
xrightmargin=0.5em
}

\usetikzlibrary{
backgrounds,
mindmap
}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{fff}
\date{\small{\jobname}}
\author{\texttt{Lol}}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}


\maketitle

\section{Background}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}

\centerline {Beamer is a \LaTeX\ class for creating beautiful     presentations.}  
 \hover<2>{
  \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
  \begin{block}{A block hovering above the slide}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item point 1
    \item point 2
\end{itemize}
  \end{block}
  \end{minipage}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

beamerthemesthlm.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthemesthlm}[2013/05/05]

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newif\if@doSectionPage
\@doSectionPagefalse
\DeclareOption{nosectionpages}{\@doSectionPagetrue}
\ProcessOptions

\mode<presentation>


\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\Circle$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\circ$ }
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{$\circ$}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}

\definecolor{sthlmLightBlue}{RGB}{90,200,250}
\definecolor{sthlmBlue}{RGB}{52,170,220}
\definecolor{sthlmDarkBlue}{RGB}{0,122,255}
\definecolor{sthlmLightRed}{RGB}{255,45,85}
\definecolor{sthlmRed}{RGB}{255,59,48}
\definecolor{sthlmLightYellow}{RGB}{255,204,0}
\definecolor{sthlmYellow}{RGB}{255,149,0}
\definecolor{sthlmPurple}{RGB}{88,86,214}
\definecolor{sthlmGreen}{RGB}{76,217,100}
\definecolor{sthlmGrey}{RGB}{142,142,147}
\definecolor{sthlmLightGrey}{RGB}{233,233,233}
\definecolor{sthlmDarkGrey}{RGB}{61,61,70}


\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=sthlmDarkGrey}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=sthlmDarkGrey}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=sthlmRed}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{copyright text}{fg=sthlmLightBlue}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=sthlmDarkGrey}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=sthlmDarkGrey,bg=sthlmLightGrey}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=sthlmDarkGrey}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=white, bg=sthlmDarkGrey}

\setbeamercolor{mini frame}{bg=sthlmLightGrey}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=sthlmDarkGrey, bg=sthlmLightGrey}

% Titlepage
\setbeamercolor{title}{parent=normal text}
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{parent=normal text}
\setbeamercolor{institute}{parent=normal text}
% Content
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{parent=palette quaternary}
% Blocks
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=sthlmDarkBlue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=sthlmDarkGrey, bg=sthlmLightGrey}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=black, bg=sthlmGreen}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=sthlmDarkGrey, bg=sthlmLightGrey}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{fg=black, bg=sthlmLightRed}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{fg=sthlmDarkGrey, bg=sthlmLightGrey}
% Notes
\setbeamercolor{note page}{fg=sthlmDarkGrey,bg=sthlmLightGrey}
\setbeamercolor{note title}{fg=white, bg=sthlmDarkGrey}
\setbeamercolor{note date}{parent=note title}
% Page Number
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=sthlmDarkGrey}

\setbeamercolor{qed}{fg=sthlmGrey}
 \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=sthlmDarkBlue}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=sthlmLightRed}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=sthlmBlue}

% Titlepage
%\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\fontsize{20}{20}}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\fontsize{15}{15}}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\fontsize{12}{14}}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\fontsize{8}{10}}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\fontsize{12}{15}}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\fontsize{8}{10}}
% Section
\setbeamerfont{section title}{size=\LARGE}
% Content
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{copyright text}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{family=\sffamily,series=\bf, size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{block title alerted}{family=\sffamily,series=\bf,     size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\scshape}
% Captions
\setbeamerfont{caption name}{}

% Titlepage structure
\def\maketitle{\ifbeamer@inframe\titlepage\else\frame[plain]{\titlepage}\fi}
\def\titlepage{\usebeamertemplate{title page}}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
    % Add background to title page
    %\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]    {background.pdf}}
    \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}
    %\vspace*{5mm}
    %\includegraphics[height=14mm]{./logo}\par
    \vspace*{24mm}
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
    \else%
        {\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]    {title}\MakeUppercase{\inserttitle}\par}%
    \fi%
    \ifx %\insertsubtitle\@empty%
    \else%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]    {subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
        \vspace*{5mm}
    \fi%
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty%
    \else%
%       {\usebeamerfont{date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{date}\insertdate\par}%
    \fi% 

    \vfill

\ifx\insertauthor\@empty%
\else%
    {\usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\insertauthor\par}%
\fi%
\ifx\insertinstitut\@empty%
\else%
    \vspace*{3mm}
    {\usebeamerfont{institute}\usebeamercolor[fg]    {institute}\insertinstitute\par}%
    \fi% 
    \vspace*{5mm}
    \end{minipage}
}

% Make Sectionhead uppercase
\newcommand{\insertsectionHEAD}{%
    \expandafter\insertsectionHEADaux\insertsectionhead}
    \newcommand{\insertsectionHEADaux}[3]{\MakeUppercase{#3}
}

\if@doSectionPage\@empty
\else
% Insert frame with section title at every section start
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begingroup
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=sthlmDarkGrey}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\centering
\vfill\usebeamerfont{section title}\textcolor{white}    {\insertsectionHEAD}\vfill
\end{frame}
\endgroup
}
\fi

\def\progressbar@progressbar{} % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta% auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb% auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht %progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd %progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim % auxiliary dimension

\progressbar@pbwd=\paperwidth
\progressbar@pbht=1.0ex

% the progress bar
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%
    \progressbar@tmpcounta=\insertframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
\progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
    \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by 1000
\multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
\divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb
    \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by 1000
  \begin{tikzpicture}[very thin]

    \shade[top color=sthlmLightGrey,bottom color=sthlmLightGrey,middle     color=sthlmLightGrey]
      (0pt, 0pt) rectangle ++ (\progressbar@pbwd, \progressbar@pbht);

      \shade[draw=sthlmDarkBlue,top color=sthlmDarkBlue,bottom     color=sthlmDarkBlue,middle color=sthlmDarkBlue] %
        (0pt, 0pt) rectangle ++ (\progressbar@tmpdim, \progressbar@pbht);

  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.0ex,center,dp=1ex]    {sthlmLightGrey}%
    \progressbar@progressbar%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}


    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
    {
    \begin{beamercolorbox}        [wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=0.3cm,rightskip=0.3cm,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex]{frametitle}
         \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\MakeUppercase{\insertframetitle}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    }


\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}    [wd=\textwidth,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex,leftskip=0.3cm,rightskip=0.3cm]{structure}%
\hfill\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
\insertframenumber%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{: }

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{
  \setbeamercolor{item}{parent=block body}
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=.5ex,dp=0.6ex,leftskip=0.5ex,rightskip=0.5ex]    {block title}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  {\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}    [sep=.5ex,dp=0.6ex,leftskip=0.5ex,rightskip=0.5ex,vmode]{block body}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}  
{\end{beamercolorbox}\vskip\smallskipamount}

\setbeamertemplate{block alerted begin}
{
  \setbeamercolor{item}{parent=block body alerted}
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=.5ex,dp=0.6ex,leftskip=0.5ex,rightskip=0.5ex]    {block title alerted}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title alerted}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  {\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body alerted}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}    [sep=.5ex,dp=0.6ex,leftskip=0.5ex,rightskip=0.5ex,vmode]{block body alerted}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block alerted end}
{\end{beamercolorbox}\vskip\smallskipamount}

\setbeamertemplate{block example begin}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=.5ex,dp=0.6ex,leftskip=0.5ex,rightskip=0.5ex]    {block title example}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title example}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  {\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body example}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}    [sep=.5ex,dp=0.6ex,leftskip=0.5ex,rightskip=0.5ex,vmode]{block body example}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block example end}
{\end{beamercolorbox}\vskip\smallskipamount}


\newcommand<>{\hover}[1]{\uncover#2{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \draw[fill,opacity=0.4] (current page.south west)
    rectangle (current page.north east);
    \node at (current page.center) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    }



\usepackage{environ}% Required for \NewEnviron, i.e. to read the whole body of the environment

\newcounter{acolumn}%  Number of current column
\newlength{\acolumnmaxheight}%   Maximum column height


% `column` replacement to measure height
\newenvironment{@acolumn}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{acolumn}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \@tempdimc=\dimexpr\ht\@tempboxa+\dp\@tempboxa\relax
    % Save height of this column:
    \expandafter\xdef\csname     acolumn@height@\roman{acolumn}\endcsname{\the\@tempdimc}%
    % Save maximum height
    \ifdim\@tempdimc>\acolumnmaxheight
        \global\acolumnmaxheight=\@tempdimc
    \fi
}

    % `column` wrapper which sets the height beforehand
\newenvironment{@@acolumn}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{acolumn}%
    % The \autoheight macro contains a \vspace macro with the maximum height     minus the natural column height
    \edef\autoheight{\noexpand\vspace*{\dimexpr\acolumnmaxheight-\csname     acolumn@height@\roman{acolumn}\endcsname\relax}}%
    % Call original `column`:
    \orig@column{#1}%
}{%
\endorig@column
}

% Save orignal `column` environment away
\let\orig@column\column
\let\endorig@column\endcolumn

% `columns` variant with automatic height adjustment
\NewEnviron{acolumns}[1][]{%
    % Init vars:
    \setcounter{acolumn}{0}%
    \setlength{\acolumnmaxheight}{0pt}%
    \def\autoheight{\vspace*{0pt}}%
        % Set `column` environment to special measuring environment
\let\column\@acolumn
\let\endcolumn\end@acolumn
\BODY% measure heights
% Reset counter for second processing round
\setcounter{acolumn}{0}%
% Set `column` environment to wrapper
\let\column\@@acolumn
\let\endcolumn\end@@acolumn
% Finally process columns now for real
\begin{columns}[#1]%
    \BODY
\end{columns}%
}

\newbox\mytempbox
\newdimen\mytempdimen

\newcommand\includegraphicscopyright[3][]{%
          \leavevmode\vbox{\vskip3pt\raggedright\setbox\mytempbox=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
\mytempdimen=\wd\mytempbox\box\mytempbox\par\vskip1pt%
\usebeamerfont{copyright text}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{copyright text}    {\vbox{\hsize=\mytempdimen#3}}}\vskip3pt%
}}

\mode
<all>
```

[image: Correct layout]
[image: "What is beamer?" should be white]
[image: Background color should be gray]

Comment: How do you compile? Anything `.dvi` related?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know, I use the standard command: latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Comment: replace it with `pdflatex.exe` and try again please.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem..

Comment: I can't believe that you are using latex with this theme. From the code it is meant to be used with xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: Should I have problems? Fortunately I have no error... However I found that also opening the pre-compiled pdf, attached from the author, shows the same error... Clearly it must be a code issue...

Comment: @Kevin: If you believe, that the cause might be a code issue, you should provide the code for checking here.

Comment: The code is on github. You can easily download the MWE here https://github.com/benjamin-weiss/hsrmbeamertheme/archive/master.zip

Comment: Without criticism, I disagree 1) I'm going to post in this moment the MWE, 2) I have compiled it using latex, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX with the same result. I think it should be interesting what's wrong here and understand why we have not expected behaviours using different PDF readers.

Comment: I have added the mwe....

Comment: Just tested on my system (Windows 7 x64, TL 2014) and I see no differences in the output when opening with SumatraPDF, Adobe Acrobat Reader, or Adobe Acrobat Pro.

Comment: No problems with MiKTeX on windows 8 x64. Viewers: TeXworks, sumatrapdf, adobe acrobat reader and pdf-xchange.

Comment: @Paul Gessler Is the section text white? Is the background grey? I tested it with two PC (x64 and x86) the pdf is correctly opened (grey background and white text section) only with Foxit. I can provide further screenshot!

Comment: @Ignasi see the above comment

Comment: @Kevin see my screenshot with the resulting PDF in all 3 PDF viewers installed on my system: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cF1Cj.png

Comment: @Paul Gessler I believe you, but look my screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tct77tkr07j206f/Screenshot%202015-04-18%2018.26.54.png?dl=0 Can you open mwe.pdf with PDF-XChange Viewer? http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer thank you so much! I really don't understand!

Comment: @Paul Gessler Can you also upload the pdf? I would like to open it in my PCs...

Comment: @Kevin: This is the pdf that I obtain https://www.dropbox.com/s/rz4kifsx8jb335y/sensetitol-1.pdf?dl=0

Comment: thank you so much @Ignasi I opened your pdf and the background was white using adobe... Finally I realized: I had an accessibility option enabled in Adobe and this changed the document color text and forced the background to white.

Comment: I apologize to everyone, I had two PCs with the same adobe configuration ... I totally forgot it since I use Foxit reader everyday

Comment: @Kevin, glad to help you.I think you could write an answer explaining how you solved the problem.

Comment: Here you are, I was planning a bounty for this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer's rule "Your presentation will look exactly the same no matter which
computer or viewer program is being used." 
If this won't happen you have to check your "accessibility option" in your pdf viewer and disable unwanted options.
Using Adobe Reader (for example):

[image]